# How to include Leaflet.TextPath or Leaflet.PolylineDecorator in Angular 6 CLI app?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet, angular-cli

I have been trying to include https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.TextPath in Angular 6 CLI application but with no success. Can anyone please guide me? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Or if this one? https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineDecorator, it also has types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to include Leaflet.TextPath you need to install Leaflet & Leaflet.TextPath in your angular-cli project and then import them as follows:

in angular.json add:

```
"styles": [
     "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
     "src/styles.css"
],
"scripts": [
   "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"
]
```

in component.ts add:

```
 ...
 import 'leaflet';
 import 'leaflet-textpath';

 declare let L; // to be able to use L namespace
 ...
```

Then you initialize your code inside ngOnInit and you place the code as indicated in the library:

```
ngOnInit() {
   your code initialization here

    ...
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uh2qns)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I actually read the same solution elsewhere and it worked, so forgot to check out StackOverflow again. Sorry! And it is the correct answer so I will accept it. Again, thanks! :)

Comment: No problem. Good to know that it helped.